# why is the layout all messed up if i expand the window, python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

i want it to expand the size accordingly if the window is expanded, so far i use the grid.row/column configure to make its weight =1 but it will be all messed up it i expand the window.

```
import time 
import tkinter as tk

#Initialise the window
clock = tk.Tk()
clock.title('Easy CLock')
clock.configure(bg='#121212')
clock.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
clock.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

border_effects = {
    "flat": tk.FLAT,
    "sunken": tk.SUNKEN,
    "raised": tk.RAISED,
    "groove": tk.GROOVE,
    "ridge": tk.RIDGE,
}

#Logo will be under the main parent
logo = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\User\VSC\Alarm\Logo1.png')
logo_size = logo.subsample(5)

#Time and Date function
def time_date():
    # current time
    current_time = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    current_date = time.strftime(r'%m/%d/%Y')
    clock.after(200, time_date)

    #Displays the time
    c_time = tk.Label(f_time, text = current_time, fg='white', bg='#121212', font=('Verdana', 30))
    c_date = tk.Label(f_time, text = current_date, font=('Verdana', 10), fg='white', bg='#121212')
    c_time.grid(column=0, row=0)
    c_date.grid(column=0, row=1)


#alarm button command
def alarm_func(): 
    #Alarm label
    c_clicked = tk.Label(f_alarm, text='Alarm Interface', fg='white', bg='#121212')
    c_clicked.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky = 'N')

def recall_frame(event):
    if event == f_alarm:
        event.grid_forget()
        f_time.grid(column=0, row =1, columnspan = 4, sticky = 'N')
    elif event == f_time:
        event.grid_forget()
        f_alarm.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan = 4, rowspan = 2)

def back_func():
    pass

#Creating Frames
f_time = tk.Frame(clock)  #Clock Button
f_alarm = tk.Frame(clock) #Alarm Buttton

#configure the frames
f_time.configure(bg = '#121212')
f_alarm.configure(bg = '#121212')

#Setting label in the frame
f_lbl = tk.Label(clock, text= ' Simplistic Clock', image = logo_size, font=('Verdana', 30), fg='white', bg='#121212', compound = tk.LEFT) 
time_but = tk.Button(clock, text='Clock', command= lambda :[time_date(), recall_frame(f_alarm)], bg='#f39c12', width = 15, relief = border_effects['ridge'])
alarm_but = tk.Button(clock, text = 'Alarm', command = lambda :[alarm_func(), recall_frame(f_time)], bg='#f39c12', width = 15, relief = border_effects['ridge'])
quit_but = tk.Button(clock, text='Exit', command = clock.quit, bg='#f39c12', width = 15, relief = border_effects['ridge'])
back_but = tk.Button(clock, text = 'Back To Home', command = back_func, bg='#f39c12', width = 15, relief = border_effects['ridge'])

f_lbl.config(borderwidth = 4, relief = border_effects['sunken'])
f_lbl.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

#Putting it on the frames
f_lbl.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 4, sticky = 'N')
time_but.grid(column = 0, row = 3)
alarm_but.grid(column = 1, row = 3)
back_but.grid(column = 2, row = 3)
quit_but.grid(column = 3, row = 3)


clock.mainloop()
```

also, why does the border in the f_lbl, simplistic clock not fully extended through out all 4 column since i put columnspan = 4 , and weight = 1 , should't it expand fully through all 4 columns?

Comment: Use `sticky='NSEW'` instead of `sticky='N'` in `f_lbl.grid(...)`.  Also need to set `weight=1` for column 1 to 3 of `clock` as well.

Comment: What does "all messed up" mean? What do you want it to look like when expanded? Should the label be ceneted vertically or stay at the top? Should the buttons stay at the bottom or stay immediately below the label? Should the buttons stretch to fill the width? Be centered? Align to the right or left?

Comment: oh yea i was not clear about that, i meant like if i expanded the the window the widgets would expand accordingly to the size of the screen where for now the button are all the way down.